# How can I remove the outermost pair of brackets enclosing a Piecewise function when it occurs in an equation?

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, notebooks, formatting, piecewise

Recently I have been annoyed by an automatic formatting in MMA, that is when a Piecewise function occurs in an equation, it will be enclosed by a pair of brackets automatically by MMA, although when it emerges solitarily, there are no such pair of brackets.

For example, suppose I have a Piesewise function `Piecewise[{{x^2, x < 0}, {x, x > 0}}]`. When it is output alone, it is like:

[image]

However, when I put this Piesewise function at the Right-Hand-Side of an equation, an annoying pair of brackets occurs:

[image]

Generally speaking, placing a Piesewise function at the end of an equation is to discuss all possible results in different cases, where the automatically added pair of brackets is unnecessary and redundant. So I was wondering, how can I remove such kind of brackets both in `Standard Form` output as well as `Traditional Form` output?

(The reason why I would like to also remove the brackets in `Traditional Form` output is that: `Traditional Form` output is the starting point of latex code conversion. If `Traditional Form`output has such a pair of brackets, then there would also be one in the `TeXForm` or the latex code MMA generates.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't mind modifying some internal symbols, you can do:

```
BoxForm`$PiecewiseSyntaxForm = SyntaxForm -> DirectedEdge;
```

Then, the parentheses should be gone.

Comment: Thanks Carl, your solution works perfectly as I have tested! And it is really impressive, since I had tried to define my own box-making functions with `MakeBoxes[]` or `Format[]`  as upper values of Piecewise, but neither succeeded. Without your suggestion, I would have never thought of modifying some internal symbols. Thanks for your creative and elegant solution!